# Entity Framework Core MongoDB Migration - Changing from Single User Field to HashSet of Users

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, entity-framework

I am working on a .NET Core ASP.NET Web API project that uses Entity Framework Core with MongoDB. In our current production environment, we have a user field in one of our MongoDB collections, which is represented as a string. However, we now need to modify the schema to allow for multiple users for a particular document, and I'm struggling with the migration process.

Here's a brief overview of our current schema:

public class MyEntity

```
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

We want to change the User field to a HashSet to accommodate multiple users for each document. However, we also need to migrate the existing data from the User field to the new Users HashSet.

I have a few questions regarding this migration process:

What steps should I take to ensure that the data from the old User field is correctly migrated into the new Users HashSet?

Are there any potential issues or considerations I should be aware of when making this schema change in a production environment?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples on how to perform this migration effectively while minimizing disruption to our production clients. Thank you!